# How to perform function deducts the quantity of availability from the pivot table if user register event in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table which are `user` `event` and `event_user`

I'm creating an event registration that have quota limit once the quota is full other user cannot register to that specific event. But the thing is I create M-M relationship for this. And `event_user` only store the `user_id` and `event_id`. How can I access the `event` table and deducts the `event_availability` once user have successfully register into the event?

```
  public function storeEvent(Request $request)
    {
    //deducts the event_availability

       $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
       $user->events()->syncWithoutDetaching([$request->event_id]);
       return redirect()->route('user.events');
```

[image: Event database]

[image: pivot table]

`Event Model`

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'event_user','event_id','user_id');
    }
```

Comment: `syncWithoutDetaching()` is it working .?

Comment: yes. it works fine for me at least now. Will I be in trouble for using it? And yes the data is stored inside my `event_user` like you see in my database above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have`event_id` from request you can update from that

```php
 $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
 $user->events()->syncWithoutDetaching([$request->event_id]);
 $event = Event::find($request->event_id);
 $event->update([
     'event_availability' => (int)$event->event_availability-1
 ]);
 return redirect()->route('user.events');
```